# macOS Catalina AudioServerPlugIn Installation

Tags: macos, audio, plugins, core-audio, macos-catalina

`CoreAudio/AudioServerPlugIn.h` says that `.driver` plugin packages must be installed in `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/`
However I don't know of any documentation that tells of how to make CoreAudio notice the appearance of the new driver (or when uninstalling, its absence). Before Catalina [beta 7] most people did something like

`sudo killall coreaudiod`

and that worked well. However in Catalina, this doesn't work anymore, and the only way I've found to get plugins loaded or unloaded is to reboot the machine, which seems a heavy handed approach for userland plugins.

So is there another way? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `coreaudiod` is catching `SIGTERM` and *not* exiting, so using `SIGKILL` fixes the problem:

`sudo killall -9 coreaudiod`

From the unix point of view, not eventually exiting on `SIGTERM` seems like a bug: FB7244673.

**UPDATE** I eventually got feedback from Apple that said the only supported method was a reboot. I’ve been ignoring that however.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me with SIP enabled on macOS Catalina 10.15 (19A546d):

```
sudo launchctl kickstart -k system/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod
```

Comment: Ooh, thank you - I didn't know about kickstart. Does it work without the -k? Which do you think is cleaner? launchctl kickstart or killall -9?

Comment: `-k` is to kill the service and relaunch it (see `man launchctl`), so I wouldn't think so. I'd use `launchctl kickstart` over `kill -9` because I'd expect it to let coreaudiod exit gracefully.